# Set the uploaded image as Featured image of post

Tags: php, wordpress, image, post

i try to make a form where users can upload a resource with a thumbnail, 3 preview images and a .rar, .zip file.

The form works and creates me a post in my custom post type.
The image so far gets uploaded too in my uploads folder.

but im not able to set the uploaded image as the featured image of the new created post.
i found alot of solutions that should work, but i cant get it to work.

Maybe someone can tell me how to do it properly :)

Below is my code that creates me the new post and saves the image in my uploads folder.

```
<?php
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_resource") {

        // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
        if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
            $title =  $_POST['title'];
        } else {
            echo 'Please enter a  title';
        }
        if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
            $description = $_POST['description'];
        } else {
            echo 'Please enter the content';
        }
        $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
        
        // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => $description,
            'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
            'tags_input'    => array($tags),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
            'post_type' => 'community-resources'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
        );
        //save the new post
        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($pid)); exit;
        //insert taxonomies

        $target_dir = "uploads/community/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["thumbnail"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["thumbnail"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }

        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["thumbnail"]["size"] > 10000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["thumbnail"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["thumbnail"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }

        add_post_meta($pid, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
    }
} ?>
```

and here is my form:

```
<div id="upload_resource_wrapper" class="container">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_resource" name="new_resource">
        <label for="title">Title:
            <input id="title" tabindex="1" name="title" size="20" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name of resource">
        </label>

        <label for="description">Description:<br>
            <textarea id="description" tabindex="3" cols="50" name="description" rows="6" placeholder="Some text about the resource"></textarea>
        </label>

        <label for="Category">Category:<br>
            <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'tab_index=3&taxonomy=category' ); ?>
        </label>

        <label for="model_file">Upload the file here:<br>
            <input accept="zip,application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed" name="model_file" size="50" type="file">
        </label>

        <label for="thumbnail">Upload the main thumbnail<br>
            <input accept=".png, .jpg, .gif, .jpeg. ,webp" name="thumbnail" size="50" type="file">
        </label>

        <label for="first_preview">Upload the first preview<br>
            <input accept=".png, .jpg, .gif, .jpeg. ,webp" name="first_preview" size="50" type="file" />
        </label>

        <label for="second_preview">Upload the second preview<br>
            <input accept=".png, .jpg, .gif, .jpeg. ,webp" name="second_preview" size="50" type="file" />
        </label>

        <label for="third_preview">Upload the third preview<br>
            <input accept=".png, .jpg, .gif, .jpeg. ,webp" name="third_preview" size="50" type="file" />
        </label>

        <label for="post_tags">Tags<br>
            <input id="post_tags" tabindex="5" name="post_tags" size="16" type="text" value="">
        </label>

        <p>
            <input action="new_resource" id="submit" tabindex="6" name="submit" type="submit" value="Publish" />
        </p>
        <input name="action" type="hidden" value="new_resource" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

    </form>
</div>
```

I tryd to use

> "add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);"

but dont know how to get the thumbnail id.

i also tried:

> "wp_insert_attachment( $attachment(dont get this),
> $_FILES["thumbnail"]["tmp_name"], 209 );

i got nothing to work :(

Comment: I would look at the wp_insert_attachment  function, when done correctly, it should return the attachment id (0 on failure), which you need in order to set the featured image.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i will test more with this function :)

Comment: I've not used it in that way, but I would recommend looking at the uploads script itself as well. I'm sure there is a build in way to use WordPress functions for this as well. As from what I see now, you make the post, but the attachment/file upload is done outside of your WordPress - which would be the same as uploading some random images into your uploads folder and expecting them to show up in the media library - it doesn't work cuz 'WordPress' doesn't know the file is there, so it also doesn't have an id, and without id, you can't connect it to other parts.

Comment: Yeah i upload it in my ftp server, i understand what you mean. thanks for the advice